# how to connect with my registered nickname on freenode webchat from xchat

Tags: irc, xchat

I have registered my nickname on freenode webchat and now I want to connect from xchat irc client.

Answer (score 2):

Just connect `/connect irc.freenode.org`;`/nick <username>` and than login

```
/msg NickServ identify <Password>
```